# Why is my program ending early?

Tags: python

I was recently able to get this to run thanks to all of your help, but I cant figure out why my program is ending here. Looking at it, `if answer == 3:` should just bring you to the next encounter, but my program is closing. Am I missing something?

```
# First Encounter (main program really)
def fi_en():
    global pow, cun, per
    print"""
It smells of damp vegetation, and the air is particularly thick. You can 
hear some small animals in the distance. This was a nice place to sleep.

1. Stay close, find some cover, and wait for food to show up.

2. Explore the nearby marsh & find the nearest river, following it downstream.

3. Walk towards the large mysterious mountain in the distance. 
"""
    answer = int(raw_input(prompt))
    if answer == 1:
        cun_one = roll_3d6()
        if cun_one <= cun - 2:
            print"""Time passes as eventually you capture some varmints.
You feel slightly more roguish."""
            cun = cun + 1
            fi_en()
        else: 
            print """Time passes and a group of slavers marches into right 
where you are hiding in the woods. They locate you, capture you, and haul you
away for a lifetime of servitude in the main city.
Goodbye %s""" % name
    elif answer == 2: 
        power = roll_3d6()
        if power <= pow - 4:
            print"""You trudge through the marshes until you eventually reach 
a large river. Downstream from the river is a large temple covered in vines,
you walk towards it. You feel more powerful."""
            pow = pow + 2
            te_en()
        else:
            print """The vegetation here wraps itself around your legs making
it impossible to move. You will most likely die here in the vegetation. 
Goodbye %s.""" % name
    elif answer == 3:
        cun_two = roll_3d6()
        if cun_two <= cun:
            print """You make your way towards the mountain and you encounter
a really large group of devil dogs guarding the entrance to the mountain."""
            dd_en()
    else: 
        print"You have gotten lost and ended up right where you started."
        fi_en()
```

And my output is:

```
It smells of damp vegetation, and the air is particularly thick. You can 
hear some small animals in the distance. This was a nice place to sleep.

1. Stay close, find some cover, and wait for food to show up.

2. Explore the nearby marsh & find the nearest river, following it downstream."

3. Walk towards the large mysterious mountain in the distance. 

> 3
Raymond-Weisss-MacBook-Pro:lod Raylug$
```

Comment: its not... 3 wont print anything if cun_two > cun

Comment: Agreed with @JoranBeasley: indent your `else` block once more so that it gets to the level of `if cun_two <= cun:`

Comment: It sounds to me like your character is too cunning.

Comment: @DavidGrant the cun variable = a characters cunning, rolled 3D6

Comment: @ Everyone else: Thanks! I cant believe i missed that else: indentation. You guys rule.

Comment: The problem is not that the final else is not indented. The problem is that there is a MISSING else, completely unwritten, for option 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined your globals anywhere. You have no "else" statement within condition three, so since cun_one is not less than/equal to your undefined cun variable, there is nothing else to do when answer == 3.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're missing a really large group of devil dogs.  Are you sure you want to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Deleted everything since you already got it working, just a comment.

You can use input('Prompt') since it automatically becomes an int, raw_input converts the input to a string, and then you are converting that string to an int, which is unnecessary.